# How can I change a label according to origin of an Activity's opening (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, switch-statement, android-fragmentactivity

An **Activity X** can be opened from the **Button A** in **Activity A** and from **button B** in **Activity B**, and it should change the label title in XML in **Activity X** accordingly.

**I don't know how to create the following condition:**

```
switch (i) {
            case 0:
                binding.lTitle.setText(getString(R.string.benefits_text));
                break;
            case 1:
                binding.lTitle.setText(getString(R.string.coverages_text));
                binding.lInfoText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
}
```

Comment: Just send the title as an argument from A or B activity and receive it in X activity. You don't need a switch case for this.

Answer (score 0):

Send the title as an intent extra (or an argument if you're using Navigation Component).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityX.class);   
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TITLE", strTitle);
startActivity(intent);
```

"strTitle" can be retrieved in ActivityX.